# Removing specified word in repeater

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to remove a specified word/line from a string in a repeater and cut the length of the string

```
  public static string CutTextLength(string text)
    {
        if (text.Length > 400)
        {
            text = text.Substring(0, 400) + "...";
            Regex.Replace(text, "<br />", "");
        }
        return text;
    }

<div class="JobContent"><%#CutTextLength(Eval("Text").ToString()) %></div>
```

When running this code i'm only reducing the length of the string but not removing all the <"br /"> tags in the string. 
Can anyone help me with my problem?

Comment: Why all this work? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: Check my last update and tell me if everything is okay :)

Answer (score 3):

You should do:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "<""br /"">", "");
```

because `Replace` doesn't alter text but returns a new string with the replacements.

**Edit**

On close reading your question I discovered you want to remove `<"br /">`. The above, updated statement should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it appear as if you can do this.

You can try this for string:

```
text = text.Replace("<br />", "");
```

If you want to use regex. This should work `<br\s*[\/]?>`

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = @"This text with <br />, <br > ";

        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"<br\s*[\/]?>", "A");

        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
```

Comment: It should work.. ive tried this... but the <br> is still displayed in the repeater

Comment: text = Regex.Replace(text, "<br\s*/?>", ""); has an Unrecognized escape sequence error

Comment: @al-web I write a little program for you, just check last my last edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62370/discussion-between-mybirthname-and-al-web).